# How can I get content from html elements using a Portable Library?

Tags: c#, html-parsing, portable-class-library

I want to "download" the HTML from `http://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow` and get the `title` and `url` of the first 5 results.

In a portable library I believe I don't have access to `HtmlDocument` and `HtmlAgilityPack` wouldn't work, or am I wrong?

How can I achieve this task keeping the lib able to execute at least on Windows Store Apps and Windows Phone?

Comment: Have you tried looking at WebDriver? I'm not sure if that would work with Windows Store Apps or Phone, but you could certainly make a desktop app that does this.

Answer (score 0):

To `download` contents is common to use the WebClient ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))
Have you able to accesse the System.Net namespace?

Comment: `WebClient` doesn't seem to be available on Portable Class Library. However I could download the content using `WebRequest` with the async methods. But I still don't have a way to `parse` the html, returning the text withing certain elements. I will either try to use `Regex` or forget the idea of a Portable Class Library.